# Preparing uneven floor for cement board

Tags: subfloor, plywood, underlayment

I have two sections of flooring that are currently uneven by about 1/4". One side is 3/4" OSB, and the other is 3/4" Plywood. Both sides are screwed and glued onto joists. I'm planning on putting cement board across both sides to prep for tile after that.

[image: floor layer diagram]

- Should I use 1/4" Plywood to bring the two sides to level? Is there something else to use instead - like self-leveling compound?
- Do I screw the plywood into the joists or just into the underlying subfloor? Screw every 6 inches - or more or less?
- Do I use glue between the plywood and the OSB? Or something else between the layers?

Comment: Your plan sounds good to me.  I think construction adhesive between the ply and OSB is a good idea.  I don't think you have to go crazy with the screws if you backer screws penetrate the OSB as well.  Self leveling compound sounds messy and unnecessary since the 1/4 will make up for it and the OSB is otherwise level.

Answer (score 2):

I would use 1/4inch Luan panels and install without adhesive. Just install to manufacturers specs. This is typically to lay it down and use 1/4 inch crown staples, 1 inch long, every 6 inches along the perimeter and 8 inches in the field.

A few things to note:

1. Make sure the subfloor is secured before using the Luan.
2. Make sure there are no protrusions from old screws/nails.
3. Clean the subfloors well. A shop vac is a good method.
4. Make sure you stagger the seams by half of a sheet (or manufacturer specs). If using a full sheet to start one run, use a half sheet for the next run. Then back to a full sheet for the 3rd.
5. Be sure to check for and avoid over and under penetration of the staples.
6. Make some 1/4 in spacers and use those to keep the luan 1/4 from the walls.

Comment: This is one of the very few places that I'd use luan, aside from craft projects. It's not a high-quality product and it's prone to staining adjacent materials, but it'll do fine as a filler layer.